# Is it possible to rebuild the website while not accesseing the original database?

Tags: database, login, username, password

Suppose I have forgotten the wordpress admin username and password, is it possible to rebuild the website (create a new database and delete/replace the original wordpress folder) while not accessing the original database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. [Just provide new connection credentials.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Default_wp-config-sample.php) WordPress will use whatever database you tell it to. You can [even use the same database with a different prefix](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs).

But it will probably be easier to regain access. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Answer (score 1):

@Kiddy - If you are not able to go to the backend of your current site, then you may access your Database and change the username/password from there. Accessing database and changing username/password from there is not for newbie and needs to be done carefully. While this is not recommended but I would say this is one handy rescue measure. Please let me know if you need any assistance in this.